# How to set up a SMTP client on Mibew?

Tags: php, email, smtp, swiftmailer, smtpclient

I'm currently using Mibew on a website, but I have a problem, I can't make the mailing system work.

I already tried typing in the SMTP settings in the files /configs/default_configs.yml

```
mailer:
    transport: "smtp"
    host: "smtp.xxx.xx.xx"
    port: 587
    user: "xxx@xxx.xx.xx"
    pass: "xxx"
    encryption: "STARTTLS"
```

I also tried setting the file vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/SmtpTransport.php

```
public function __construct($host = 'smtp.xxx.xx.xx', $port = 587, $security = 'STARTTLS')
    {
    ...
public static function newInstance($host = 'smtp.xxx.xx.xx', $port = 587, $security = 'STARTTLS')
    {
```

I also tried using encryption/security false/null but that didn't work either.
I did manage to make the Drupal mailing system work tho, so I know the server is working fine, but I must be missing somthing in Mibew.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Oh wait, I'm supposed to create a mailer section in /configs/config.yml don't I?

Comment: Typing the settings in /configs/config.yml didn't work tho...